# Show that, if $\gcd(r,s)=1$, then $\mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s \cong \mathbb{Z}/rs$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that, if $\gcd(r,s)=1$, then $\mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s \cong
  \mathbb{Z}/rs$. Show that this does **not** hold if $\gcd(r,s) \neq 1$.
  Hint for the first part: there are two possible maps: either $(\bar
  a,\bar b) \mapsto \overline{sa+rb}$ in the forward direction, or
  $\bar a \mapsto (\bar a, \bar a)$ in the reverse direction; however
  **these are not inverse to each other**: the composition of the
  two directions is multiplication by $r+s$.  Hint for the second
  part: Show that the order of every element in $\mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s$
  is a factor of $\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$. (Why do the two maps given before no longer define isomorphisms in this case?)

Comment: possible dublicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310304/mathbbz-m-times-mathbb-z-n-is-cyclic-if-and-only-if-gcdm-n-1

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

$\to$Can you find element $a$ and $b$ of order $r$ and $s$ respectively in $\mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s$ ?

$\to$Now as $(r,s)=1$ and $ab=ba$ can you show that $o(ab)=rs$ ?
If you find it difficult you can see it here  [Order of $ab$ if $a$ and $b$ commute and $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108381/order-of-ab-if-a-and-b-commute-and-langle-a-rangle-cap-langle-b-rangle)

$\to$Use the fact that every cyclic group of order $rs$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}/rs$ .